# Laravel: ACL and Roles for Users. Am I thinking this right?

Tags: laravel, permissions, acl, roles

I am about to define permissions for users in my project. I checked the laracasts videos regarding ACL, Roles and Permissions.
I have a doubt. Do I need Roles for normal users?
I mean, in my project a user should be able to create / update / delete his own posts, he should be able to comment on his own posts and posts by other users and delete his posts and posts left by others on his own posts.
The point is: do I really need to define Roles for this kind of permissions? Shouldn't I just define some policies like can / can't post / update / delete etc. and only define roles for admins?

Comment: You can create an acl table with entity_type, entity_id and user_id. So if an entity belongs to a user he will be able to crud else just read. Entity type can be a post or a comment. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a full featured, powerful Roles/ACL system but if you are storing both admin and basic users in the same table then you do need something to distinguish between them. This could be something as simple as a Role field as a string on your users table e.g. `Admin` or `Basic`, or even a boolean `is_admin` field.

This would give you the ability to implement a Policy or Middleware to prevent basic users accessing the admin panel, and you can have permission checks to ensure a user can't update other users posts etc.

If you don't foresee needing anything more complex in future then this would suffice. However, as your app becomes more mature, you might wish to have a more advanced roles system, for example where a user needs to have multiple roles.

Comment: ok, I get the the Roles system can be of use. What I really don't get or fail to understand is if even with the Roles system I need to define normal Roles for normal users when all I need is to check if they can modify their posts / comments. I don't even get how this should be done through roles if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to define a role for every user...

It's probably a good idea to, however, you can 'hardcode' and make some assumptions about some of the access...

For example:

If you assume that anyone who is logged in can make a post and can edit their own post, you don't need to make a role for users to say "can_make_post", just have a check saying "if user is logged in, then let them make a post"

then if you say, have an admin area, then you can go "if user a has role 
 with the 'admin_access' permission, then allow access"

---

It would be a good idea to have roles for everything, as it allows more customisation, however, your the one designing it, if you don't need the customisation, you can probably just make some assumptions like above.